# Pandas pick the higher value for each unique id

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df of customers

```
CUST_ID | SEGMENT | AREA
  1     |  B      | CAD
  1     |  A      | RAM
  2     |  B      | CAD
  2     |  C      | RAM
  3     |  B      | RAM
  4     |  A      | RAM
```

I want to count the unique number of `CUST_ID` per `SEGMENT` so I did

```
df.groupby(['SEGMENT'])['CUST_ID'].nunique()
```

However if there are same `CUST_ID` with different `SEGMENT` types then the number per `SEGMENT` gets inflated. I want to pick the highest value `SEGMENT` per `CUST_ID` and then count. A being the highest and C being the lowest. So the resulting df would look like:

```
CUST_ID | SEGMENT | AREA
  1     |  A      | RAM
  2     |  B      | CAD
  3     |  B      | RAM
  4     |  A      | RAM
```

and the count would be

- A - 2
- B - 2
- C - 0

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: df.sort_values(by=['CUST_ID','SEGMENT']).drop_duplicates(subset='CUST_ID')['SEGMENT'].value_counts()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try groupby `CUST_ID` column then filter rows by getting the `min` value of `SEGMENT` column.

```py
out = (df.groupby(['CUST_ID'])
       .apply(lambda g: g[g['SEGMENT'].eq(g['SEGMENT'].min())])
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

NOTE: Since you want to pick the highest value SEGMENT per CUST_ID and then count, **A** being the highest and **C** being the lowest, in ASCII talbe, `A` is 65, `C` is 67. When comparing, A actually is smaller than C. That's why use `min` here.

```
print(out)

   CUST_ID SEGMENT AREA
0        1       A  RAM
1        2       B  CAD
2        3       B  RAM
3        4       A  RAM
```

```py
res = out.value_counts('SEGMENT')
```

```
print(res)

A    2
B    2
Name: SEGMENT, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

You can go like this:

```
(df.sort_values('SEGMENT').drop_duplicates('CUST_ID') # remove duplicates, keep only first 'CUST_ID'
   .groupby('SEGMENT')['CUST_ID'].nunique() # or just `.size()` because there are no duplicates
)
```